# how to use dax filter to condition on column?

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns, measure, monthcalendar

[image: here is image of formate which i want]

i want to add another column which is the count of enrolled in the same month and register on same month

where IsEnrolled - Enrolled students
RegisteredOn - date of Registration on website

[image: want output like this image]
where R-M Registered on respective month
E - M Enrolled on respective month

Comment: Your sample data not matching with your explanation.

Comment: @mkRabbani yes i know but there is something missing just want an idea how to filter out